# how to change order of appearance through z-index?

Tags: html, css

I must be a little bit foggy still on how `z-index` works because I have this jsFiddle and I can't seem to reorder some elements the way I need to. I want the red box to appear behind the text. Can someone explain how I can do this?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sightofnick/u2pa4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `z-index` is not in pixels, [it's just an integer](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index). Rather than `z-index:10px`, try `z-index:10`. Note also that this only applies to *positioned elements*, meaning those elements that have been set to either `absolute` or `relative`.

Comment: Your element must also have `position:(relative|absolute)` for the `z-index` to have effect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use position:absolute | relative for the nav too

see this http://jsfiddle.net/u2pa4/4/